# Почему кнопка не становится активным после ввода?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtcreator

кнопка createButton должна быть активной после того как пользователь вводит данные, далее идет сигнал к функции enableFindButton(const QString &text),которая внутри себя вызывает функцию проверки на правильность ввода и если правильно то становится активной. Но почему когда запускаю программу и ввожу данные ничего не происходит с кнопкой, она по прежнему серая.
хэдэр

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <ui_mainwindow.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void checkingForCorrectInput(bool result);

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void enableFindButton(const QString &text);
    bool checking_for_correct_input();



};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

исходник

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <ui_mainwindow.h>
#include <QtGui>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->cancelButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::close);

    connect(ui->lineEditFrom, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &)), this, SLOT(enableFindButton(const QString &)));
    connect(ui->lineEditTo, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &)), this, SLOT(enableFindButton(const QString &)));
    connect(ui->lineEditStep, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &)), this, SLOT(enableFindButton(const QString &)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::checkingForCorrectInput()
{
    ////
////
}


void MainWindow::reading_values()
{

}

void MainWindow::enableFindButton(const QString &text)
{
    bool result = MainWindow::checkingForCorrectInput();
    ui->createButton->setEnabled(result);
}
```

Comment: Этот код не должен даже компилироваться.

Comment: А русский просто зашкаливает